# find if a number in an array fits in a range between two selected numbers

Tags: json, xcode, swift3

Here is a code where I thought it could take `age` from a JSON then find if it  fits in a range of selected items ( which is a number and it's string)

```
for (key, subJson) in json {

    ages.append(subJson["age"].string)

    if let ageFrom = Int(self.DropDownFrom.selectedItem!),
       let ageTo = Int(self.DropDownTo.selectedItem!) {           
       for age in ages {

           guard let ageint = Int(age!) else { return }

           switch ageint
                  {
                   case (ageFrom...ageTo):
                    print ("Age is in range")
                    default:
                    print ("Nope, not this time")
     }
      }
      }
```

However, it shows that I need to unwrap an optional value! But I think I already did:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

**UPDATED**

thanks to  Nirav D. I solved the issue but now I feel like I did it in the wrong way.

```
   if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
   //Handle the results as JSON
     var ages = [String?]()

     let json = JSON(value)
     for (key, subJson) in json {

         if let ageFrom = Int(self.DropDownFrom.selectedItem!),
         let ageTo = Int(self.DropDownTo.selectedItem!) {
      if ageFrom...ageTo ~= subJson["age"].int  {

          print(subJson["name"])
          print(subJson["religion"])
```

What I'm trying to do is go through the ages returned from API and see if one of them fits in the range. And if there is I then would like to take the data coming of the age such as name and image.

Comment: You are getting this exception on which line ?

Comment: `if let ageFrom = Int(self.DropDownFrom.selectedItem!)`

Comment: @leo0019 What is the type of `selectedItem`?

Comment: it's a number as a string

Comment: https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown the library

Comment: @leo0019 Try once printing `selectedItem` because it is optional string and you are force fully wrapping it, check the log for this `print(self.DropDownFrom.selectedItem)` is it nil, check and reply here.

Comment: it's actually `nil` ! @NiravD

Comment: @leo0019 That was the issue.You haven't selected item properly check it.

Comment: @leo0019 After selecting Item is it working?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137055/discussion-between-leo0019-and-nirav-d).

Comment: Can you please look at the updated question @NiravD

Comment: @leo0019 Don't get your question?

Comment: the api will return a json that contains  age, name, and image. when the user pick a range, I want the code to check if the `age` that comes with the json fits in the range the user picked. And if it does I want to pull the name and image of that specific json. @NiravD

Comment: nvm I did it. Thanks

Comment: @leo0019 That great that you solved it.